# Best practice for declaring constants that are used in several Activities

Tags: android, convention

In several tutorials, I've seen result codes set as "private static final int"s at the top of pertaining activities. To me this does not seem like the best way to do this since I find myself having to constantly refer to other classes to find the correct code rather than referring to the same code created somewhere else.

Is there a better way to do this? Is it bad practice to just make a utility class to hold the common result codes, request codes, data keys, etc? I've just never seen this done before.

Comment: `since I find myself having to constantly refer to other classes`, `make a utility class to hold the common result codes` How the two methods differ? Won't you just be making `"private static final int"s at the top of ` the **common class**?

Comment: No, from multiple different activities I want to return a "RESULT_LOGOUT" that propegates back to the root activity that performs the function of logging out a user. I'm wondering if I should declare this as a public static final int in the root activity, in a different resource file, in a utility class, across all classes that need it (as a private int), etc.

Comment: I find the propagation necessary since I want to provide back-button functionality as well.

Comment: `if I should declare this as a public static integer in the root activity, in a different resource file, in a utility class` ... wherever: it's always a "public static int" declaration. And you have to refer the containing class.

Comment: Editted, I was reckless with my wording. These will be constants not variables.

Comment: See the above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to keep this variables in Gradle build and use them like this: `BuildConfig.VARIABLE`

Example:

In gradle file:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
     buildConfigField "java.lang.String", "DATABASE_NAME", "\"db_name\""
    }
}
```

In Java:
      `BuildConfig.DATABASE_NAME`

Pros:

- can change constants values for different builds
- there is one place with all program constants
- auto generated (BuildConfig) by IDE/Gradle

References:

- 0.14.3 http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system
- http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/

Comment: Isn't this a **constant** definition?

Comment: yes it is :). I think that all computer programs have some kind of constants. At some level of abstraction you need to say that **X = 1**, the question is how and when do it.

Comment: I understood he want consts. *private static **final** int*

Comment: In my opinion when he was saying "vars" he meant "consts" :). I read code not comments ;)

Comment: I appreciate this answer, I find myself learning more about gradle every day since I've made the switch to studio. I feel myself inclined to simply use a constant class since I'm most familiar with that though I may dabble in this method to see how I like it.

Comment: And I no longer feel inclined to use a constant class. This is fantastic, thank you for exposing me to this!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's personal preference, although it seems more meaningful to have all your statics in utility class. The tutorials probably show them in Activies for simplicity which is far easier to understand than using utility classes when they only need a couple of statics.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share constants for few classes, you can create special "constants" class and refer to it.

```
package ru.kopeyko.***;

/**
 * class for holding various CONSTANTs for '***' app
 * 
 * @author Andrey Kopeyko <andrey@kopeyko.ru>
 */

public final class Const {

    public static final String UUID_DEFAULT = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
    public static final String VERSION_CODE = "versionCode";
    public static final long ONESECOND = 1000L;
    public static final int POSITIONS_MAX_DAYS = 32;
    public static final long DB_MAINTENANCE_INTERVAL = 1*86400*1000L;

}
```